# User profile is not loading Stack Exchange reputation league page

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, reputation-leagues

It appears there's a bug on the [stackexchange.com reputation league page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues). When navigating to the "All Time" section for [Stack Overflow](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/) and [Meta Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/alltime/meta/) via the drop-down list or by entering the URL in the browser, users typically expect to see their user profile at the top of the sections, provided they have an account on the respective site. However, currently, the user profile fails to load, and instead, a loader is displayed with the tool-tip "Loading user information".

This issue seems to persist exclusively for Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange, although similar problems may occur on other sites as well.

**GIF for the reference:**

[image: stackexchange.com loader issue]

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me.  have you tried again?

Comment: @AaronBertrand This is a confirmed bug, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396998/341152

Comment: @AaronBertrand I understand, and I was not criticizing, merely trying for some attention toward solving the problem. As it stands now, the enthusiasm for closing the "duplicate" exceeds the need for duplication to confirm a `bug`. Please reopen this post, it is needed to call attention to the problem. Finally, questions are asked to solicit answers. Is there and answer forthcoming?

Comment: @AaronBertrand The problem with closing this post is that it precedes my post  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396998/341152 and that the two posts don't overlap; rather both posts report problems that are indicative of a more widespread problem, i.e. they are not identical. Prior this issue occurred and was fixed, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396998/341152 now it is broken again, so a better bug fix is probably needed. Does the re-occurrence of a solved problem constitute duplication? I think rather it supports the need for more support.