# Long loading time on reputation page

Tags: support, bug, reputation, profile-page, performance

When I open my [Stack Overflow profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276052/aioobe?tab=reputation) (when logged in) it takes a long time for the page to load. The first request takes at least 7 seconds. This is easily reproducible. It happens in all browsers I've tested, and on all my devices, including laptop (using Wi-Fi) and phone (regardless if I use [LTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4G) or Wi-Fi).

All other webpages load instantly.

I suspect there's a heavy backend query that just takes a long time to execute.

I can live with it, but 7 or more seconds is definitely an inconvenience, and if it's indeed a long running database query, I suspect it puts a significant load on the backend if this is a common issue.

[image]

The same for `tab=tags`:

[image]

---

It doesn't seem to repro for any one else. Could it be this inboxy thing that I've never clicked on that has just increased to a problematic level? See:

[image]

Comment: Too much reputation ... we can help with that ... ;)

Comment: runs fine for me by the way. I'm in Western Europe, in case that matters.

Comment: Does it matter on what tab you're sorted? I tried Jon Skeet and it looked like [sorting on post](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation&sort=post) took longer (still not as long as you claim, but noticeable).

Comment: May be related: [User profile is not loading Stack Exchange reputation league page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396992)

Comment: _Does it matter on what tab you're sorted?_ Let me check in a bit... The page loads reloads quickly for a few minutes after initial load. Presumably due to some page being cached server side.

Comment: No repro, your reputation page loads within half a second for me. My own does as well, on various sites. Even when it has to graph 9 years of history on CR, it's surprisingly quick.

Comment: @Mast, ack. Good data point.

Comment: No repro here either, and frankly I’ve always been amazed at how fast page loads are, universally - even (or especially?) now that I know what’s behind the curtain. That said, there is always room for improvement. I did profile all the queries on that page and I’ve put the one that takes the longest (225 milliseconds!) on my radar for tuning. But not this weekend, given today’s workload.

Comment: Any chance you can do it logged in as me? (Adding an image in the question that I suspect you don't see if you're not logged in as me.)

Comment: No, I can't log in as you. But _wow_. How is your notification count that high? I have never seen anything like that.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue on Space Exploration - reputation league stats load but usernames do not - just the spinny thing. It has been happening since last night and is still happening.

Comment: @AaronBertrand That's not exactly unusual if a high-reputation user comes off of a suspension.

Comment: @Sonic Sure, but I wonder if we really have to count that... instead of just **∞** maybe. :-)